# How to delay toast message until button pressed in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm currently working on a kotlin application, somewhere inside the app a toast message gets displayed onClick, but i need to be able to delay the message until the next button press. Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

According to kotlin documentations, toast delay timer only comes in two types;

```kotlin
//Toast.LENGTH_SHORT: lasts about 2seconds
//Toast.LENGTH_LONG: lasts about 3seconds

if (diceOneValue != diceTwoValue) { 
            val showToast = Toast.makeText(
                this,
                """You rolled $diceTwoValue & $diceOneValue,
                Count ${diceTwoValue + diceOneValue}!
            """.trimIndent(),
                **Toast.LENGTH_SHORT**
            )
            showToast.show()

        }
```

I need to be able to hold toast message until button is pressed, or close the toast message when button is pressed regardless of the delay time.

Comment: You can't customize the time  duration of Toast. Alternatively, you can look into [snackbar](https://m3.material.io/components/snackbar/overview) to achieve this.

Comment: Couldn't you just move the ```Toast.(...).show()``` to the needed location? If not: Create a new variable ```Toast t = new Toast.(...);``` and call ```t.show();```, once you need it.

Comment: Thanks @Nitish, i'll check snackbar out.

Comment: @Z-100 Toast.(...).show() is just where i need it to be, the problem is not where i need it but the time for it to appear on the screen. i need to be able to control the toast message appearance with button click

Comment: @StephenAdegbite wouldn't that be just as easy, as putting it in a clicklistener?

Comment: @Z-100 yes, a clickListener could work to cancel the toast but can it hold the toast longer than the default timer?

Comment: @Nitish can you please show how to accomplish this with a snackbar?

Comment: For the Toast issue: "LENGTH_LONG" is just an integer. ```Toast.makeText(context, "", 5).show()``` would also work.

Comment: And for the Snackbar: LENGTH_INDEFINITE would be your friend, as it makes the Snackbar show up until the next one shows up OR you destroy the old one: ```Snackbar.make(view, Message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Action", null).show()```

Comment: @StephenAdegbite use Tosty library to create custom toast with custom delay time. See this https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty